# regex matchesInString in Swift 2

Tags: regex, swift, nsregularexpression

The `toCamel()` function in this String extension is supposed to remove any `_` followed by a character in the middle of a String, and replace the two with the character to uppercase.

```
public extension String {
    public func rangeFromNSRange(aRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let s = advance(self.startIndex, aRange.location)
        let e = advance(self.startIndex, aRange.location + aRange.length)
        return s..<e
    }
    public var ns : NSString {return self as NSString}
    public subscript (aRange: NSRange) -> String? {
        get {return self.substringWithRange(self.rangeFromNSRange(aRange))}
    }

    public var cdr: String {return isEmpty ? "" : String(characters.dropFirst())}

    public func toCamel() throws -> String {
        var s = self
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "_.", options: [])
        let matches = regex.matchesInString(s, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, s.ns.length)).reverse()
        for match in matches {
            print("match = \(s[match.range]!)")
            let matchRange = s.rangeFromNSRange(match.range)
            let uc = s[match.range]!.uppercaseString.cdr
            s.replaceRange(matchRange, with: uc)
        }
        if s.hasPrefix("_") {s = s.cdr}
        return s
    }
}
```

The thing is that `matchesInString` doesn't return the matches where the `_`is already part of the previous match. And thus, it gives the following results :

```
try "hello_world".toCamel()    //"helloWorld"

try "hello__world".toCamel()   //"hello_world"

try "hello___world".toCamel()  //"hello_World"
```

How to go around this?

Comment: SO what do you expect in each case, all `helloWorld`?

Comment: yes exactly @ZoffDino

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change you pattern to `_+(.)`. This matches one or more underscores followed by another character. The round brackets place that character into a **capture group**. You can get back the captured character with `rangeAtIndex`

```
public func toCamel() throws -> String {
    var s = self
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "_+(.)", options: [])
    let matches = regex.matchesInString(s, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, s.ns.length)).reverse()
    for match in matches {
        print("match = \(s[match.range]!)")
        let matchRange = s.rangeFromNSRange(match.range) // the whole match range
        let replaceRange = match.rangeAtIndex(1)         // range of the capture group
        let uc = s[replaceRange]!.uppercaseString
        s.replaceRange(matchRange, with: uc)
    }
    if s.hasPrefix("_") {s = s.cdr}
    return s
}
```

Examples:

```
"hello_world".toCamel()              // helloWorld
"hello___world".toCamel()            // helloWorld
"hello_beautiful____world".toCamel() // helloBeautifulWolrd
```

---

### Update for Swift 2.1.1

```
public extension String {

    public func rangeFromNSRange(aRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let s = self.startIndex.advancedBy(aRange.location)
        let e = self.startIndex.advancedBy(aRange.location + aRange.length)
        return s..<e
    }
    public var ns : NSString {return self as NSString}
    public subscript (aRange: NSRange) -> String? {
        get {return self.substringWithRange(self.rangeFromNSRange(aRange))}
    }

    public var cdr: String {return isEmpty ? "" : String(characters.dropFirst())}

    public func toCamel() throws -> String {
        var s = self
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "_+(.)", options: [])
        let matches = regex.matchesInString(s, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, s.ns.length)).reverse()
        for match in matches {
            print("match = \(s[match.range]!)")
            let matchRange = s.rangeFromNSRange(match.range) // the whole match range
            let replaceRange = match.rangeAtIndex(1)         // range of the capture group
            let uc = s[replaceRange]!.uppercaseString
            s.replaceRange(matchRange, with: uc)
        }
        if s.hasPrefix("_") {s = s.cdr}
        return s
    }
}
```

Comment: ` 'advance' is unavailable: call the 'advancedBy(n)' method on the index`

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems in your code.

First the regex matching your requirement should be `_+[^_]{1}`.

Second in your `cdr` computed proterty, `String(characters.dropFirst())` only exclude the first `_` character. You may use `String(characters.suffix(1))`

Edited code:

```
public extension String {
    public func rangeFromNSRange(aRange: NSRange) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let s = advance(self.startIndex, aRange.location)
        let e = advance(self.startIndex, aRange.location + aRange.length)
        return s..<e
    }
    public var ns : NSString {return self as NSString}
    public subscript (aRange: NSRange) -> String? {
        get {return self.substringWithRange(self.rangeFromNSRange(aRange))}
    }

    public var cdr: String {return isEmpty ? "" : String(characters.suffix(1))}

    public func toCamel() throws -> String {
        var s = self
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "_+[^_]{1}", options: [])
        let matches = regex.matchesInString(s, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, s.ns.length)).reverse()
        for match in matches {
            print("match = \(s[match.range]!)")
            let matchRange = s.rangeFromNSRange(match.range)
            let uc = s[match.range]!.uppercaseString.cdr
            s.replaceRange(matchRange, with: uc)
        }
        if s.hasPrefix("_") {s = s.cdr}
        return s
    }
}
```

I tested this in the playground.

Comment: When I tested your solution with `hello____world`, it returns `hello___World`. It removed the first underscore only.

Comment: @ZoffDino Sorry, I re-tested my solution, it's working. Did you copy-paste the entire snippet?

Comment: @Fujia my badd... didn't copy `cdr`

Answer (score 0):

try `NSRegularExpression(pattern: "_+.", options: [])`

---

You should also read [NSRegularExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/).

`+` Match 1 or more times. Match as many times as possible.